# Recompile Symfony container manually

Tags: symfony, docker

I am trying to create a dockerized symfony application. The problem is that the DI container gets built during the Docker container build which means I can't really inject runtime parameters into it. So far my solution was to clear the cache in the container entrypoint, but I realized that in some cases this might be a quite heavy operation, so I created a custom compilation function in the AppKernel based on the kernel's boot function:

```
/**
 * Recompiles the container without warming up the whole cache.
 *
 * Can be called upon docker container start to inject custom parameters.
 */
public function compile()
{
    // Load class cache
    if ($this->loadClassCache) {
        $this->doLoadClassCache($this->loadClassCache[0], $this->loadClassCache[1]);
    }

    // Initialize bundles to be able to parse configurations
    $this->initializeBundles();

    $class = $this->getContainerClass();
    $cache = new ConfigCache($this->getCacheDir().'/'.$class.'.php', $this->debug);

    $container = $this->buildContainer();
    $container->compile();
    $this->dumpContainer($cache, $container, $class, $this->getContainerBaseClass());
}
```

This function would now be called upon each Docker container start (before the application starts).

Is this a safe operation? Should I assume that any cache warmers might rely on the container parameters? (Since I only change the container parameters runtime, the services and everything else should remain the same).

Originally asked in a symfony repo issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19525

PR to my custom repository: https://github.com/webplates/symfony-standard/pull/42

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to run cache:clear / cache:warmup when building the container in prod environment? Then never touch them again? 

I dont get the difference between your manual approach and and empty cache directory?

Comment: I mean: Symfony does the same internally. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Cache clear is not a good idea because it might be a heavy operation (as I pointed out). Leaving the cache dir empty or just manually removing the built container will both end up in a warmup. In some cases, warmup could even take a minute, which is not acceptable in a containerized infrastructure.

Comment: What I do here is that I simply recompile the DI container files, but leave the rest of the cache as is.

Comment: Ah, okay. Maybe this could help:  https://github.com/Incenteev/DynamicParametersBundle ? It can override the container parameters with env vars, with fallback to the compiled ones. Thus there is no need to compile the container again.

Comment: In general you approach should work. I do manual on-demand container creation that way in a non full-stack app.

Comment: I know this bundle and it's not an ultimate solution. It will work with parameter resolution, but it doesn't actually replace parameters, the container still exposes the ones from the built cache. The question here is whether I should expect that the warmup relies on container parameters (eg. database details).

Answer (score 0):

This can't be answered in general, it completely depends on the bundles you use and the parameters that are changed. For example, if your routing depends on a parameter (to set a host on a route for example), it is *not* enough to only rebuild the container, a warm up is needed to rebuild the routing.